# ошибка добавлении репозитория в Deepin

Tags: java, python, linux, repository, deepin

пытаюсь поставить яву на deepin 15.4 
вот что вываливается при попытке добавить репу:

```
    apollo@apollo-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
 Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK7 / JDK8 / JDK9). There are no actual Java files in this PPA.

More info (and Ubuntu installation instructions):
- for Oracle Java 7: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
- for Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Debian installation instructions:
- Oracle Java 7: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html
- Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

Oracle Java 9 (for both Ubuntu and Debian): http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html

For JDK9, the PPA uses standard builds from: https://jdk9.java.net/download/ (and not the Jigsaw builds!).

Important!!! For now, you should continue to use Java 8 because Oracle Java 9 is available as an early access release! You should only use Oracle Java 9 if you explicitly need it, because it may contain bugs and it might not include the latest security patches! Also, some Java options were removed in JDK9, so you may encounter issues with various Java apps. More information and installation instructions (Ubuntu / Linux Mint / Debian): http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmptr3vmhhm/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmptr3vmhhm/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key C2518248EEA14886: public key "Launchpad VLC" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 474, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 432, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 430, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Нет такого файла или каталога: 'S.gpg-agent.browser'
```

как профиксить я не знаю. ось чистая, с офф источника. питон поставил
пытаюсь делать по этой инструкции
[Ссылочка](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-ubuntu-apt-get-ru)

Comment: на всякий случай, если вы не в курсе: можно устанавливать и openjdk, причём не из «левой файлопомойки» (чем являются все эти «ppa»), а из вполне дистрибутивного репозитория. восьмая версия в нём, вроде бы тоже имеется: http://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/deepin/packages/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/

Comment: а она вроде как под девелопинг не конает))

Comment: @АртурБелов как вы сделали такой вывод?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле фиксить ничего не надо.

add-apt-repository все что надо уже сделал. Это он на выходе пытается удалить временные файлы. А поскольку временные файлы удаляются еще и из дочернего процесса, то возникает такая ошибка.

Дальнейшей работе apt эта ошибка не мешает.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала

```
sudo apt install software-properties-gtk gnupg dirmngr
```

а потом по этому мануалу

http://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/como-instalar-o-oracle-java-8-em-debian-via-repositorio/

Comment: Опишите - чем поможет предлагаемая вами ссылка, тем боле на португальском, в решении задачи автора вопроса.